# Simple update takes forever

Tags: sql-server, update, index-tuning

On SQL Server I want to update a 0/1 interger value for a specific set of records. For some reason this takes very long (let it run for 2 hours, still not finished). I can't figure out what is wrong or what to tweak.

The query:

```
 update workorder set INCTASKSINSCHED=0 where siteid = 'RAILINFRA' AND HISTORYFLAG=0 AND ISTASK=0;
```

There are 282320 workorder records, only 103565 are for the RAILINFRA site. So it should be very, very fast.

In SQL Management studio I have this as an estimated execution plan. You can see a huge cost at the workorder_ndx1 index. I'm not sure why that is...

[image: Estimated execution plan for update]

I tried to count the number of records, this works very fast:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  workorder WHERE   siteid ='RAILINFRA' AND HISTORYFLAG=0 AND ISTASK=0;
```

1 row: 5430
Execution time 0sec

[image: Excution plan for count]

The select statement took just under 1 sec, and has a different execution plan:

```
SELECT * FROM  workorder WHERE   siteid ='RAILINFRA' AND HISTORYFLAG=0 AND ISTASK=0;
```

Gives the 5430 rows

[image: Execution plan for select]

This is the information of the indices used:

workorder_ndx1 (clustered)

- SITEID
- WONUM

workorder_ndx24 (non-clustered)

- HISTORYFLAG
- ISTASK
- WONUM

There is only one index with the to be updated field INCTASKINSCHED

workorder_ndx38 (non-clustered)

- WONUM
- INCTASKINSCHED
- SITEID

I do have the XML's of the executionplans (slqplan-files), let me know if you need more information from them.

I suspect there is somekind of a loop that it uses an index that needs updating, but not sure why that should be the workorder_ndx1 index, because it doesn't include the INCTASKINSCHED field.

Comment: Check if the update statement isn't waiting for some locks to be released. Look for the wait type of this process.

Comment: any advice how to do that? (I'm quite new to SQL server)

Comment: select * from sys.dm_exec_requests and replace sesssinid with your update session id to see status of update statement.You can see here if your update is running only.if not check in select * from sys.sysprocesses

Comment: Check out sp_WhoIsActive. Run it while your queries are executing. http://sqlblog.com/files/folders/beta/entry42453.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out there was a trigger on the samen table that also updates it, that forces an update for the index used. It works near instant with the trigger disabled.